# Trying to load random images using jquery -- Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onload

I'm brand new to javascript and jquery. I'd like to load a random image when I load the page.  I found some code that looked really easy, but I can't seem to make it work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Everything looks good to me....

My HTML is below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.23.org/19999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>A  Site Just For Me!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica:400,700|Francois+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js"></script> 
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="me_css.css">

</head>

<body >         
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="greeting"></div>
            <div id="happypic"></div>
            <div id="banner"></div>
            <div id="banner2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my javascript file:

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {

});

//This is where i set up my greeting.

var nowDate=new Date();
var nowHour=nowDate.getHours();
var greeting;

if (nowHour<11)
{
    //good morning
    greeting="Good morning";
}   
else if (nowHour<16)
     {
        //good afternoon
        greeting="Good afternoon";
     }
     else 
     {
        //good evening
        greeting="Good evening";
     }
//document.write("<center><h1>"+greeting+", Loser!");//

// This is where i put my random picture chooser
// pictures

//random image experiment

var hawaiiPix=new Array("hawaii1.jpg", "hawaii2.jpg", "hawaii3.jpg", "hawaii4.jpg", "hawaii5.jpg");
$('<img src="img/'+hawaiiPix[Math.floor(Math.random()*hawaiiPix.length)]+'">"').appendTo('#happypic');

var images = ["hawaii1.jpg", "hawaii2.jpg", "hawaii3.jpg", "hawaii4.jpg", "hawaii5.jpg"];
$('<img src="images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('#banner');

$('<h1>Hello</h1>').appendTo('#banner2');
```

Any insight would be much appreciated...

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting.  I will pay closer attention next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your jQuery code is outside the **ready function**, so it is running before the DOM has been loaded, so it cannot add the image because those elements don't exists in the HTML page yet.

One way is to put the loading of your `myjs.js` file before `</body>` so when it executes the items are loaded (you'll need to remove the jQuery.ready code) or you can put it inside the ready block like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 //This is where i set up my greeting.
    var nowDate=new Date();
    var nowHour=nowDate.getHours();
    var greeting;

    if (nowHour<11)
    {
        //good morning
        greeting="Good morning";
    }   

    else if (nowHour<16)
    {
        //good afternoon
        greeting="Good afternoon";
    }
    else 
    {
        //good evening
        greeting="Good evening";
    }
    //document.write("<center><h1>"+greeting+", Loser!");//

    // This is where i put my random picture chooser
    // pictures

    //random image experiment

    var hawaiiPix=new Array("hawaii1.jpg", "hawaii2.jpg", "hawaii3.jpg", "hawaii4.jpg", "hawaii5.jpg");
    $('<img src="img/'+hawaiiPix[Math.floor(Math.random()*hawaiiPix.length)]+'">"').appendTo('#happypic');

    var images = ["hawaii1.jpg", "hawaii2.jpg", "hawaii3.jpg", "hawaii4.jpg", "hawaii5.jpg"];
    $('<img src="images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('#banner');


    $('<h1>Hello</h1>').appendTo('#banner2');
});
```

The best way is to move the loading of jQuery and your JS file at the bottom of the html code.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That fixed it!  It seems so obvious that the code needed to be inside the function AFTER you said it, but before I didn't understand.